# IllegalViewOperationException: View with tag 11 is not registered as a root view

Tags: android, react-native, expo

- Hi everyone,
  I am newbie in React Native and Expo. After publishing my app on Google Play, I received a crash report that I'm unable to re-produce in my local environment. It appears to occur exclusively in the production version. Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? I would appreciate that a lot.
  `

```
Exception com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: View with tag 11 is not registered as a root view
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ShadowNodeRegistry.removeRootNode (ShadowNodeRegistry.java:46)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.removeRootShadowNode (UIImplementation.java:185)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.removeRootView (UIImplementation.java:169)
  at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.removeRootView (UIManagerModule.java:381)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke (JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
  at com.facebook.jni.NativeRunnable.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```

- I tried to reproduce it in my local environment and search for the possible code which might cause error